# Reverse engineer the structure of a database based on queries that are used

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc

I am reverse engineering a java code and trying to create a Database Structure.
i encounter many queries like

```
    select AVG(SEN.READING_SENSOR_TEMP) as AVGTEMPREAD, from sensor_readings sen
```

Now I am confused as to what is the db, table and column. Please help me in understanding the Query.

Comment: It might be worth your while to learn sql.  It would make this project simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB: there is no name of DB
Table: sensor_readings (directly after from)
Column: READING_SENSOR_TEMP (AVG function take column as an argument)
```

Probably `SEN` is confusing for you. `SEN` is an `alias` - you can use it instead of full name of the table.

Comment: Thanks Parado. You are savior.